# Need foreach to generate a column from an implode in php laravel blade

Tags: php, html, laravel, zurb-foundation

Hi i am trying to generate a column everytime a foreach runs throught the elements of an implode but i cant get it to work properly

This is my controller

```
$disponibilita = CvDisponibilita::selectRaw("cv_disponibilita.*, regioni.nome_regione as regione")
        ->where('curriculum_id', '=', $data->curriculum_id)
        ->leftJoin('regioni',"regione_id","=","codiceistat_regione")
        ->get();


    foreach ($disponibilita as $item){
        $item->province = Provincia::whereIn("sigla_provincia",explode(",",$item->province))->get();
    } return view('emails.hai-nuova-candidatura',compact('skills','data','lingue','disponibilita'));
```

And this is my blade

```
@foreach($disponibilita as $disp)
<table class="row">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first last">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <table class="row">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="small-12 large-2 columns first">
                      <table>
                        <tr>
                          <th>
                            <h5>{{$disp->regione}}</h5>
                          </th>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                      <table class="spacer">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td height="2px" style="font-size:2px;line-height:2px;">&#xA0;</td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </th>
                    @foreach($disponibilita->province as $disp2)
                    <th class="small-12 large-2 columns last">
                      <table>
                        <tr>
                          <th><h5>{{$disp2->implode('nome_provincia',', ')}}</h5></th>
                          <th class="expander"></th>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </th>
                    @endforeach
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </th>
            <th class="expander"></th>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
@endforeach
```

This is my output(dont mind the css)
[image: current output]

This is what i need it needs to look likem as you can see every element has its own column unlike my output where 2 elemnts are smashed together in the same column

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is, loop through the array and put each array item inside a HTML table column.

So, the code will look like this (According to your description)

```
<table>
  <tr>
    @foreach($disponibilita as $single_disponibilita)
      <th>$single_disponibilita->val</th>
    @endForeach
  </tr>
</table>
```

This will generate a column for each item.